# Pyvista access to VTK file values

Tags: python, pyvista

I have a VTK file and I can open that using `pyvista`. When I open this file in any 3D viewer applicatoins (e.g. Paraview) I can see the points and their values (there are many points distributed in X,Y,Z and each point has its own value).

In `pyvista` I can only see the points coordinates and don't know how to access the values (or labels) at each coordinate.

```py
import pyvista as pv
pd = pv.read('data.vtk')
pd.points

# UnstructuredGrid (0x20fef143e28)
#  N Cells: 0
#  N Points:    80851
#  X Bounds:    -2.570e+03, 2.550e+03
#  Y Bounds:    -1.280e+03, 1.280e+03
#  Z Bounds:    -1.075e+03, 2.048e+02
#  N Arrays:    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to the `point_arrays` property, which you can use to access scalars associated with each point.

If you've assigned a value to each point within a mesh, you can access it with the `point_arrays` property, which behaves like a python dictionary.  For example, when generating a `Sphere` within `pyvista`, the normals are included with the mesh and can be accessed with:

```py
>>> import pyvista as pv
>>> mesh =  pv.Sphere()
>>> mesh.point_arrays['Normals']
pyvista_ndarray([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
                 [ 0.        ,  0.        , -1.        ],
                 [ 0.10811902,  0.        ,  0.99413794],
                 ...,
                 [ 0.31232402, -0.06638652, -0.9476532 ],
                 [ 0.21027282, -0.04469487, -0.97662055],
                 [ 0.10575636, -0.02247921, -0.99413794]], dtype=float32)
```

See the [Basic API Usage](https://docs.pyvista.org/getting-started/simple.html?highlight=point_arrays#basic-api-usage) for more details.

Comment: It does return a array containing the coordinates. But I am looking for the values (e.g. at each coordinate, a value between 0 and 1 is assigned that I can see them in PyVista) I want to find the values as well as the coordinates.

Comment: I think you should open an issue on https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support.  You're referring to the `point_arrays` property, which you can use to access scalars associated with each point.